# Размещение String[] в TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Как добавить в TextBox массив String[] из метода? Возможно стоит воспользоваться другим инструментом, типа ListBox? Цель - разместить все строки из массива в поле на MainWindow. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, пользуйтесь ListBox или любым другим ItemsControl

Comment: @АндрейNOP Каким методом можно добавить данные из метода? Items.Add(string[]) передает только название объекта, а не содержимое

Comment: `foreach (var my_string in my_strings) items.Add(my_string)` ?

Comment: @tym32167, а там разве нет  метода `AddRange` ?

Comment: @tym32167 туплю, забыл про цикл foreach. Спасибо

Comment: @morphey83 К сожалению - нет

Comment: `MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = MyStringArray;`

Comment: @АндрейNOP еще немного и можно советовать биндинг :)